# Excel how get number of hours in a time interval?

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns with:

```
Night shift start: 19:00

Night end: 04:00
```

And I have some date columns with for each day..

```
Work started: 07:30

Worked ended: 22:00
```

I want to get the number of hours as a decimal that is between the night shift start and night end. I need to calculate the number of "night shift hours" for worked hours.

From comment: I do not want to get the total number of hours. I want to calculate the number of "night shift hours" and that is hours between 19:00-04:00

Comment: `between the night begin and night start` Shouldn't that read `between the night begin and night end`?

Comment: @jpw - Yub, I have just updated my question

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(B1-A1 < 0, 1-(A1-B1),( B1-A1))
```

Assuming that cell A1 contains start, B1 contains end time.
Let me know, if it helps OR errors.

<strike>Time without date is not enough to do the subtraction considering the start can be the night before today.</strike>

Are you OK to try VBA?

EDIT: The formula is meaningful within 12 hour limit. I will see if it can be made simpler.

Comment: I use this to calculate the total hours: `=(IF(B2<A1;B2+1;B2)-A1)*24`

Comment: This will get you the decimal version if you are multiplying by wage rate. =TEXT(*if statement*,"##.#0")

Comment: The if statement in your answer does not help it returns -7,5 and does not match the night shift range..

Comment: Can you give example of data that you are trying the above formula with? It gives 11:30 when A1 contains 19:00, B1 contains 6:00, to me.

Comment: http://www.amino.dk/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Discussions.Components.Files/11/0246.example_5F00_nightshift.xls

Comment: Do you know understand what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: I think, I am getting what you are looking at. Let me see if I can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Given start time in B5 and end time in C5 this formula will give you the decimal number of hours that fall in the range 19:00 to 04:00

`=MOD(C5-B5,1)*24-(C5<B5)*(19-4)-MEDIAN(C5*24,4,19)+MEDIAN(B5*24,4,19)`

format result cell as number

Answer (score -1):

just substract the two dates to get the difference in days, and multiply by 24 to get the difference in hours

```
=(B1-A1)*24
```

this is correct when both B1 and A1 contain a datetime value, but in case your cells contain just a time value, with no day value, and given that the calculation spans the night (there is a day change in between) you need to add one day to the difference:

```
=IF(B1<A1,1+B1-A1,B1-A1)*24
```

Comment: I do not want to get the total number of hours. I want to calculate the number of "night shift hours" and that is hours between `19:00-04:00`