# Time within a time interval

Tags: time, excel-formula, intervals

I found this formula here in the forum and it works perfectly when the time shift ends after midnight. I tried the same formula with ending time `23:00` but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

I want it to count hours between 18:00–23:00.

Given start time in `B5` and end time in `C5` this formula will give you the decimal number of hours that fall in the range `19:00` to `04:00`.

```
=MOD(C5-B5,1)*24-(C5<B5)*(19-4)-MEDIAN(C5*24,4,19)+MEDIAN(B5*24,4,19)
```

Comment: Can you post a link to where you found the formula in the first place?

Comment: Yes I found it here given by Barry Houdini: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654303/excel-how-get-number-of-hours-in-a-time-interval/47200762?noredirect=1#comment81350665_47200762

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=MEDIAN((C5+(C5*24 < B5*24))*24,18,23)-MEDIAN(B5*24,18,23)
```

B5 is start date, C5 is end date.

Comment: I tried it on where cell G24 is 15:00 and F24 is 06:00 but it gives me 5 hours as answer, it should turn out to be 0

=MEDIAN((G24+(G24*24<18))*24;18;23)-MEDIAN(F24*24;18;23)

Comment: You're right, there was a small bug - should be fixed now, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks! you´re a genius. I´ve been trying to solve this one for 1,5 days.

Comment: Thanks - and you're welcome! Please mark it as accepted answer if it answers your question.